# Copy to clipboard from php command line script in Windows 7

Tags: php, windows

I have a php (5.5) script which I run from the command line in Windows 7. Something like this:

```
C:\php-5.5.5\php.exe C:\scripts\putString.php
```

My question is, is it possible to copy something to windows clipboard from the script? I want users to have some text available in the clipboard after running this script from the command line. How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add some intermediate result to the clipboard, instead of the output of the entire script

```php
//...your script...
$someVar="value";
shell_exec("echo " . escapeshellarg($someVar) . " | clip");
//rest of script...
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted

Comment: If your string is very long you might want to [save the contents in a temporary file](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) and pass the file using the command `type $tempPath | clip`. Remember to [unlink](http://www.php.net/unlink) the temporary file afterwards.

Comment: Also this is really handy when using git bash in windows

Comment: You should strongly consider using something like this: `shell_exec('echo ' . escapeshellarg($someVar) . ' | clip')`, otherwise you may risk serious command injection risks!

Comment: this solution is vulnerable to shell injection! for example if $someVar contains `foo | del /S C:\windows\system123` then the command will try to delete your `C:\windows\system123` folder !

Comment: @hanshenrik if you think this answer can be improved to account for that, you should edit it

Comment: @chiliNUT ok, it's still not perfect (it will choke on binary data, like null bytes or images), but it's no longer vulnerable to shell injection :) btw escapeshellarg() is basically the shell version of PDO::quote()

Answer (score 2):

Use clip:

```
C:\php-5.5.5\php.exe C:\scripts\putString.php | clip
```

Answer (score 1):

first i'd like to point out that @chiliNUT's solution is NOT safe, it's vulnerable to shell injection, for example

```
$someVar="foo | del /S C:\windows\system123";
shell_exec("echo $someVar | clip");
```

will try to delete your C:\windows\system123 folder, as the command becomes

```
echo foo | del /S C:\windows\system123 | clip
```

...

here is a portable function that should work on Windows 7+ (PowerShell 2+), X.org-based linux systems, and MacOS:

```
function getClipboard():string{
    if(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Windows"){
    // works on windows 7 + (PowerShell v2 + )
    // TODO: is it -1 or -2 bytes? i think it was -2 on win7 and -1 on win10?
        return substr(shell_exec('powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"'),0,-1);
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Linux"){
        // untested! but should work on X.org-based linux GUI's
        return substr(shell_exec('xclip -out -selection primary'),0,-1);
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Darwin"){
        // untested! 
        return substr(shell_exec('pbpaste'),0,-1);
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("running on unsupported OS: ".PHP_OS_FAMILY." - only Windows, Linux, and MacOS supported.");
    }
}
```

as for writing TO the clipboard:

```
function setClipboard(string $new):bool{
    if(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Windows"){
        // works on windows 7 +
        $clip=popen("clip","wb");
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Linux"){
        // tested, works on ArchLinux
        $clip=popen('xclip -selection clipboard','wb');
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Darwin"){
        // untested! 
        $clip=popen('pbcopy','wb');
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("running on unsupported OS: ".PHP_OS_FAMILY." - only Windows, Linux, and MacOS supported.");
    }
    $written=fwrite($clip,$new);
    return (pclose($clip)===0 && strlen($new)===$written);
}
```