# Access clipboard from php-cli?

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-line-interface, clipboard

Is there some way to access the clipboard from php-cli? I particularly need it for Windows, but a cross-platform solution would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

portable function that should work on Windows 7+ (PowerShell 2+), X.org-based linux systems, and MacOS:

```
function getClipboard():string{
    if(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Windows"){
    // works on windows 7 + (PowerShell v2 + )
    // TODO: is it -1 or -2 bytes? i think it was -2 on win7 and -1 on win10?
        return substr(shell_exec('powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"'),0,-1);
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Linux"){
        // untested! but should work on X.org-based linux GUI's
        return substr(shell_exec('xclip -out -selection primary'),0,-1);
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Darwin"){
        // untested! 
        return substr(shell_exec('pbpaste'),0,-1);
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("running on unsupported OS: ".PHP_OS_FAMILY." - only Windows, Linux, and MacOS supported.");
    }
}
```

as for writing TO the clipboard:

```
function setClipboard(string $new):bool{
    if(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Windows"){
        // works on windows 7 +
        $clip=popen("clip","wb");
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Linux"){
        // tested, works on ArchLinux
        $clip=popen('xclip -selection clipboard','wb');
    }elseif(PHP_OS_FAMILY==="Darwin"){
        // untested! 
        $clip=popen('pbcopy','wb');
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("running on unsupported OS: ".PHP_OS_FAMILY." - only Windows, Linux, and MacOS supported.");
    }
    $written=fwrite($clip,$new);
    return (pclose($clip)===0 && strlen($new)===$written);
}
```

Comment: not working on windows 10..

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien how are you running php? is it php-cli or apache+mod_php or nginx+php-fpm ? (or something else?)

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien found a little issue on win10: the very last byte wasn't copied by getClipboard (if clipboard contained "123", then getClipboard would just copy "12").. fixed that now, but it works for me on win10 with php-cli 7.4.13

Comment: ..sorry my bad..my antivirus detect it as malicious....

Comment: This composer package is a more robust version of this answer: https://packagist.org/packages/asvvvad/clipboard

Comment: @BurhanAli on Windows, not really, my approach works on Powershell 2+ / Windows XP + and that package's approach works on Windows 8 + (i made a pull request to fix it though: https://github.com/asvvvad1/clipboard/pull/1 )

Answer (score 0):

$someVar="value";

shell_exec("echo $someVar | clip");

ref: [Copy to clipboard from php command line script in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926038/copy-to-clipboard-from-php-command-line-script-in-windows-7)

Comment: this allows you to write to the clipboard, but it doesn't allow you to read from the clipboard. also this is lethal, what do you think happens if $someVar  is ```foo && rm -rfv --no-preserve-root /``` ?  the command would become ```shell_exec("echo foo && rm -rfv --no-preserve-root / | clip");``` and it would wipe your harddrive.  the least you'll have to do is escape the variable, eg ```shell_exec("echo ".escapeshellarg($someVar)." | clip");``` - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php